# Python - HTML Parser - Narrow Down Scrape

Tags: python, web-crawler, html-parser

I am new to HTML Parser. I have written a Spider in Python which aims to crawl a website. I have included my code below. This code specifically looks for all URLs which are identified with an "a" start tag and a href attribute. However, I would like to further filter this by only scraping URLs which contain a specific word. I am currently working around this by outputting my "crawled" URLs to a txt file. From there i read the content of this file, filter it by my key word and then write the results to a new txt file. However, I feel it would be more efficient if I could narrow the focus of my crawler to only look at "a" tags, href attributes and "where word XXX" exists.

Is there a way in which I can expand the "if" statement within the def handle_starttag function to only scrape urls which contain a specific word? The word is usually contained in the href link in the html also.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib import parse


class LinkFinder(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self, base_url, page_url):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.page_url = page_url
        self.links = set()

    # When we call HTMLParser feed() this function is called when it encounters an opening tag <a>
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for (attribute, value) in attrs:
                if attribute == 'href':
                    url = parse.urljoin(self.base_url, value)
                    self.links.add(url)

    def page_links(self):
        return self.links

    def error(self, message):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have an easier time using [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) than the lower level `HTMLParser`.

To add the additional filter to your current implementation, you could add an additional parameter to your `LinkFinder` class, store the value, and use it in the conditional:

```py
class LinkFinder(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, base_url, page_url, url_filter):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.page_url = page_url
        self.links = set()
        self.url_filter = url_filter

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for (attribute, value) in attrs:
                if attribute == 'href' and self.url_filter in value:
                    url = parse.urljoin(self.base_url, value)
                    self.links.add(url)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @dskrypa! I am currently reviewing some tutorials in BeautifulSoup4 :) Thanks for the tips on the above. How would i declare the value, i.e. the keyword which I want to include in my program? Thanks you again

Comment: The new `url_filter` param in the answer is what is intended to be the keyword that you are looking for.